# Application Storage Should Be Enabled Thrown by Silverlight 5 and Safari in Windows 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, deployment, safari

Im currently having a hard time of solving this problem. I had just upgraded my website to Silverlight 5 and this message is what i get:

[image]

I have take a look at the Microsoft-Silverlight Configuration dialog box and verified that application storage is enabled:

[image]

This is happening only to safari browser and windows 7 OS. Please any help will be appreciated much.

Thanks,

Comment: AFAIK, Safari is officially supported only on MacOS. Our app even won't launch in Safari on Win7. I suggest you use either MacOS, or another browser.

Comment: @PavelGatilov Hi, Thanks for helping out. I know its kinda weird that we are trying to create this site and be browsed by safari in Windows 7. But we are trying to solve this problem due to client request.

Comment: You should understand that using a not supported technology may cause unpredictable expenses, and your clients should probably know about it. The rest is up to you. Hopefully, SL5 will work with Safari in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, Silverlight 5 doesn't support Anything Safari inside Windows 7, but it works well on Mac. Here's a good site for your questions.

http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/locale/en-us/html/installation-win-SL5.html

Maybe tell your client that it really isn't supported. Hope this helped.

Comment: Gee I think your correct dude.. hope someday they will support this feature. Thanks